# nhibernate sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Entity Photos belongs to Property entity  and one property can have many photos. Mapping is fine, creating data is doing ok. In db my photos are stored for example
Id 1 binarydata PropertyId(100) 
And Property article with Id of 100 have reference to many photos. I'm write all this to say that my creation of data is ok and mapping as well.

So, the problem is on loading photo collection on showing property details. 
I need to load photo collection inside session, so I'm stuck here.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            MyDomain.Property data = null;
            using (//session)
            {
                using (//transaction)
                {
                    data = session.QueryOver<MyDomain.Property>()
                        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                        .Fetch(x => x.Photos).Eager //empty
                        .Fetch(x => x.Features).Eager
                        .SingleOrDefault<MyDomain.Property>();

                  //I was thinking here to call 
                  // data.Photos = GetMyPhotos(id);
                    tx.Commit();
                    return PartialView("_HomePageDetailsPartial", data);
                }

            }
            //return PartialView("_HomePageDetailsPartial", data);        
        }
```

As you can see in this I tried with data.Photos = GetMyPhotos(id); but on debug I have Error message Cannot update identity column 'Id'.
Cannot update identity column 'Id'.
Even this work, I'm convinced that there is some more elegant way to retrieve photos collection for particular property.

My mappings

```
public class PhotoMap : ClassMap<Photo>
    {
        public PhotoMap()
        {
            Table("Photo");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ImageMimeType).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.Property).Column("PropertyId");

        }
    }

public class PropertyMap : ClassMap<Property>
    {
        public PropertyMap()
        {
            Table("Property");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            ...
            References(x => x.Features, "FeaturesId");
            HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("Id").Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

DB snapshot
Two tables, Property and Photo.

```
Id int not null
Title nvarchar(255) not null
PhotoId int not null
```

Photo table

```
Id int not null
ImageData varbinary(MAX) null
ImageMimeType varchar(50) null
PropertyId int not null
```

Relationship is as follows:

FK_Property_Photo

```
Primary Key table        Foreign key table
--------------------------------------------
Photo                    Property
--------------------------------------------
Id                       PhotoId
```

Comment: are you sure your mapping is okay? Because that first Fetch should already populate your Photos collection. I'd have a look at the generated SQL and see if NHibernate already tries loading the related photos and if these queries have errors in them.

Comment: I can't understand why you need `data.Photos = GetMyPhotos(id);`. Then you get your `Property data`  from session with eagerly loaded Photos and Feautures, data.Photos are already loaded with all photos.

Comment: Can you please include your mapping. Your mapping is incorrect compared to your database schema and it's attempting to update a value.

Comment: update my question with mappings.

Comment: So you let NH generate the Database Schema?

Comment: nope, just updated question with db snapshot

Comment: I'm agree with Nikolay, there's something wrong with this:
data.Photos = GetMyPhotos(id)
What's you doing inside "GetMyPhotos(id)
"?

Comment: @Nikolay data.Photos = GetPhotos(id) is where I tried to implement workaround since my eager loading is empty, so I can see now that is addon which I dont need. So, if anyone can tell me is my mapping ok?

Do not pay too much attention on that GetMyPhotos(id) line.
When I dont use that line of code I dont have error message Cannot update identity column 'Id' but still my collection is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your KeyColumn in your mapping is wrong. KeyColumn is used to define the foreign key column in the n-table. In your case, the key column should be "PropertyId".

in addition: why do you have a PhotoId column in your property table if the relation between property and photo is 1:n?

Comment: so you basically saying that I need to get rid of my PhotoId column since I already have relationship on Photo table using PropertyId?

Will you be kind to pass me example of mapping HasMany for PropertyMap and PhotoMap

Comment: Yep, I think GarlandGreene is right. As for me I usually don't use KeyColumn explicit.

Comment: You would just have to define the KeyColumn as "PropertyId" and you should be fine. In PropertyMap: HasMany(x => x.Photos).KeyColumn("PropertyId").Cascade.All(); By the way, that is also the reason inserts work: on insert, by default the child entity is responsible for identifying the parent entity. As only the relation from the property to its photos is broken (and not the relation from a photo to its parent property), inserts work and selects don't.